# XCTWaiter.Result does not reveal which case each result is when printed by XCTAssertEqual

Tags: swift, xctest

I am using `XCTWaiter` to wait for an expectation, and then I assert that the expectation was fulfilled by asserting that the result of the wait is `.completed`, like so:

```
let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5)
XCTAssertEqual(result, .completed)
```

Functionally, this works fine, however if the assertion fails, the error message unhelpfully doesn't tell me which result case is the outcome.

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("XCTWaiterResult") is not equal to ("XCTWaiterResult")

This is inconvenient for debugging. How can I get the assertion failure message to report the case of `XCTWaiter.Result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `XCTWaiter.Result` conform to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`. By implementing the `debugDescription` property, you can provide the String interpretation of the `XCTWaiter.Result` for when the error message is constructed.

```
extension XCTWaiter.Result: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    public var debugDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .completed:
            return "Completed"
        case .incorrectOrder:
            return "Incorrect Order"
        case .interrupted:
            return "Interrupted"
        case .invertedFulfillment:
            return "Inverted Fulfillment"
        case .timedOut:
            return "Timed Out"
        @unknown default:
            fatalError("Unknown XCTWaiter.Result case")
        }
    }
}
```

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Timed Out") is not equal to ("Completed")